# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know how I can get my question undeleted. I don't understand what happened with my question. This is the question I'm talking about. [How can I see what is in my smartstore soups?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22891/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-smartstore-soups)

I asked this question on dec 23 at 14:55. 2 hours later it is put on hold because it is considered off topic. The message suggests I should edit the post and make it more on topic. Very ok about that but one hour later it gets deleted and I lose the ability to edit it. And that's it. I'm out of options.

My question is clearly about how to be able to work with the smartstore, which is available in the SalesforceMobileSDK. Smartstore is maybe not a direct technology from Salesforce but they do use it to offer offline capability to mobile Salesforce developers.

So maybe I was not clear enough but since the documentation about the SalesforceMobileSDK is very limited online I would expect we would help and not just delete questions because I was not clear enough.

Comment: I do agree things get closed/deleted too fast at times. I tried to undelete but only mods can.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and ask it again? I mostly focus on mobile/ SF1 topics so I'll be happy to help out.

Comment: I reopened your question

Answer (score 4):

You are correct and it should be undeleted.  I apologize for voting to close it as it is not off topic.  I just voted to reopen it.  Thank you for posting about it.

Four more reopen votes are needed from other users to reopen it, although it might need to be undeleted by a moderator as well.

[How can I see what is in my smartstore soups?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22891/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-smartstore-soups)

Comment: So, only moderators can vote to re-open this? It gives me a broken link if I try to access it.

Comment: @GauravKheterpal I think you need to have enough rep/privileges to see it (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).  I can see it and I can click the reopen link on the question, but when I click the undelete link it tells me that only a moderator can undelete it. Can you see anything here? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/reopen

Comment: For me, it gives 'There are no items for you to review'.

Comment: It's reputation-related. I can see this question, I can see "undelete (2)" votes but when I try to cast mine I'm getting "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted". So you need to poke either @Saariko (who made the decision to delete it) or any other moderator: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: @eyescream - You can click the reopen link, just not the undelete link.  I believe that the (2) is actually part of the reopen, not the delete.  I flagged it for moderator attention.